# Oracle ADF Unexpected Null Pointer Exception When accessing view objects in a seperate thread

Tags: multithreading, nullpointerexception, oracle-adf

I have a webservice in adf that treats requests,  I use methods from a jar that run through view object iterators and so on.

In treating a request I call a method from the said jar that initializes a separate thread that manipulates and compares rows from view objects in that separate thread,

I am getting random exceptions like the following:

```
## Detail 0 ##
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetIteratorImpl.initViewRowSetIteratorImpl(ViewRowSetIteratorImpl.java:227)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetIteratorImpl.(ViewRowSetIteratorImpl.java:176)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.createNewRowSetIterator(ViewRowSetImpl.java:1434)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.createViewRowSetIterator(ViewRowSetImpl.java:1485)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.getDefaultRowSetIterator(ViewRowSetImpl.java:1704)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.setRangeSize(ViewRowSetImpl.java:2936)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.doCreateViewLinkAccessorRS(ViewObjectImpl.java:16080)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.createViewLinkAccessorRS(ViewObjectImpl.java:16171)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.AssociationDefImpl.get(AssociationDefImpl.java:472)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewAttributeDefImpl.get(ViewAttributeDefImpl.java:949)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowStorage.getViewLinkAccessorResult(ViewRowStorage.java:1528)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowStorage.getAttributeInternal(ViewRowStorage.java:1827)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowImpl.getAttributeValue(ViewRowImpl.java:1923)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowImpl.getAttributeInternal(ViewRowImpl.java:866)

and

```
## Detail 0 ##
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowImpl.getUseViewLogicGroupDef(ViewRowImpl.java:6078)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowStorage.getViewAttributeDef(ViewRowStorage.java:1432)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowStorage.getAttributeInternal(ViewRowStorage.java:1778)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowImpl.getAttributeValue(ViewRowImpl.java:1923)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowImpl.getAttributeInternal(ViewRowImpl.java:866)

and

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetIteratorImpl.initViewRowSetIteratorImpl(ViewRowSetIteratorImpl.java:227)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetIteratorImpl.(ViewRowSetIteratorImpl.java:176)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.createNewRowSetIterator(ViewRowSetImpl.java:1434)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.createViewRowSetIterator(ViewRowSetImpl.java:1485)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.getDefaultRowSetIterator(ViewRowSetImpl.java:1704)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.setRangeSize(ViewRowSetImpl.java:2936)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.doCreateViewLinkAccessorRS(ViewObjectImpl.java:16080)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.createViewLinkAccessorRS(ViewObjectImpl.java:16171)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.AssociationDefImpl.get(AssociationDefImpl.java:472)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewAttributeDefImpl.get(ViewAttributeDefImpl.java:949)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowStorage.getViewLinkAccessorResult(ViewRowStorage.java:1528)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowStorage.getAttributeInternal(ViewRowStorage.java:1827)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowImpl.getAttributeValue(ViewRowImpl.java:1923)
>       at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowImpl.getAttributeInternal(ViewRowImpl.java:866)

The same method when it runs without the jar ( same code like in the jar but as a part of the same project ), it executes perfectly fine.

Could you please tell me why a  NullPointerException is raised?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use the Business Components(ViewObject,Entities... etc)  inside a thread.

**There is no context (FacesContext cannot be initialized )**.So you have to pass the ApplicationModule as a paramter to your method. But it will take a lot of time for processing

So the best way to access your data is to use CallableStatments PreparedStatments with Java Data Source connection.